# Can't get simple loop working right

Tags: python, loops

```
def getMSTestPath(testPath):
    dllFilePath = r'C:\Users\bgbesase\Documents\Brent\Code\Visual Studio'
    msTestFilePath = []
    dllConvert = []
    full_dllPath = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(testPath):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj'):
                #testPath = os.path.abspath(files)
                testPath = files.strip('.vbproj')
                msTestFilePath.append(testPath)
                #print testPath
                #print msTestFilePath

    for lines in msTestFilePath:
        ss = lines.replace(r'.', r'-')
        #print ss
        dllConvert.append(ss)

    for lines in testPath:

        dllFilePath = dllFilePath + '' + lines + '\bin\Debug' + '.dll' + '\n'
        full_dllPath.append(dllFilePath)
        print full_dllPath

    msTestFilePath = [str(value[1]) for value in msTestFilePath]
    return msTestFilePath


testPath = [blah.APDS.UnitTests
blah.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests
blah.DataManagement.UnitTests
blah.FormControls.UnitTests ]

ss = [ blah-APDS-UnitTests
blah-DatabaseAPI-UnitTests
blah-DataManagement-UnitTests
blah-FormControls-UnitTests ]
```

I need to walk through the path and first: Get all files that end in `.UnitTests`, and return them as a list `testPath`. Then, i have to convert all of the `.`'s into `-`'s and return that list as ss.

This is where I'm stuck, I need to go through a loop to for as many tuples are in `testPath` I need to  add `dllFilePath + testPath + '\bin\Debug\' + ss + '.dll'

However, I can't get it to work, and I don't know why, the output is just some nonsense, :(
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `.strip()`; it treats its argument as a *set* of characters, not a specific sequence.

As such, you are removing all characters in the set `{'.', 'v', 'b', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'j'}` and that removes far more than you think it does:

```
>>> 'blah.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj'.strip('.vbproj')
'lah.APDS.UnitTests'    # Note that 'b' was removed from the start
```

Use string slicing instead:

```
testPath = files[:-len('.vbproj')]
```

or use `os.path.splitext()`:

```
testPath = os.path.splitext(files)[0]
```

Demos:

```
>>> 'blah.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj'[:-len('.vbproj')]
'blah.APDS.UnitTests'
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.splitext('blah.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj')[0]
'blah.APDS.UnitTests'
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, your solution fixed part of the problem, however when I go to run it, the output looks like this: `C:\\Users\\bgbesase\\Documents\\Brent\\Code\\Visual StudioC\\bin\\Debug.dll\no\\bin\\Debug.dll\no\\bin\\Debug.dll\np\\bin\\Debug.dll\ne\\bin\\Debug.dll\nr\\bin\\Debug.dll\n.\\bin\\Debug.dll\n`